# What tips would you give me to texture rough surfaces and walls?

Tags: texturing, uv

I need help with blender texturing. I want to texture a wall with a Victorian paper texture at the top of the face/wall and a wooden texture at the bottom of the face/wall. The wooden part is extruded and bevelled and I don't know how textures work in blender. This is how it looks:[image: This is Eevee by the way.]

And this is the texture I want to put on the top part of the wall (There is also a bevelled extrude above the wall I want to texture):

[image]

Image of comment result:
[image]

Comment: hello, maybe show your current object, the kind of texture you're trying to achieve, and maybe if you want to do it procedurally or with an image texture?

Comment: A few ways of doing this :

in edit mode ( face select) you can select faces and assign individual materials to them, but you need to add your images to the OBJECT first.

With your object selected head into the materials tab - 

Add your 3 materials to the object using the little plus button next to the box at the top

Still in edit mode, select the faces you want to be textured with wallpaper, and click 'assign (back in the materials tab)

Deselect those faces and move on to your next material .

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the advice, but what I seem to get is something like 2 plain colours with no detail on them, I'll attach the image of what it looks like now in the main question.